# Django: non primary-key auto incremented field

Tags: django, autofield

is there a possible way to create a `non primary-key auto incremented field` like a `AutoField/BigAutoField` that is not prone to failure(duplicated ids, ...) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [**`post_save`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#post-save) signal to create one, like this:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class YourModel(models.Model):
   auto_field = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, default=None)

@receiver(post_save, sender=YourModel)
def update_auto_field(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.auto_field = instance.pk
        instance.save()
```

Comment: i'll try this in a minute

Comment: something is off with your signals, it keeps breaking, raise Error: `Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.
`

Answer (score 0):

We create `AutoFieldNonPrimary` and use a custom field like below

```
from django.db.models.fields import AutoField
from django.db.models.fields import checks


class AutoFieldNonPrimary(AutoField):

    def _check_primary_key(self):
        if self.primary_key:
            return [
                checks.Error(
                    "AutoFieldNonPrimary must not set primary_key=True.",
                    obj=self,
                    id="fields.E100",
                )
            ]
        else:
            return []

class YourModel(models.Model):
   auto_field = models.AutoFieldNonPrimary(primary_key=False)
```

Comment: it will raise an `AssertionError`, django only supports 1 `AutoField` at the moment (`id` is also an `AutoField`)

Comment: @DjangoDO I didn't think. Can you give it a try ? I didn't test it.